# Streaming SQL Server 2008 Recursive CTEs

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a set of data from a table (`TableA`) which relates to itself through `TableB`. Parents in `TableA` have children in `TableA`. Those children might also have children. Nothing amazing here.

I have a top-level set of rows from `TableA` that I need to operate on. Before I can operate on those rows, I must have each child row on hand. I must be able to operate on each top-level row of `TableA` (and it's children) as fast as possible in my application.

I can't find a way to do this.

Using a recursive CTE (`TableA` top-level set as anchor, `TableB->TableA` join as union), does not fulfill the requirements. The entire top-level set from `TableA` is returned in the CTE before it works on level 2 of the children. Then it works on level 3. Then level 4, etc. Since my top-level set is some 400,000 plus rows, my client application cannot begin working on rows until the ENTIRE dataset has been batched up on the server.

I need a better way to do this. I've tried streaming a flat set of top-level `TableA` rows to the client, and having the client issue the recursive CTE statement repeatedly for each top-level `TableA` row. This actually works. But there's too much noise. The sustained row retrieval rate is too large due to the repeated reissuing of statements.

I need a creative solution.

Snippet of the per-record CTE I'm using. In this example, TableA is Member, and TableB is MemberReplacement. I ripped out most of the select statement in the middle, and most of the joins.

```
WITH T_MemberRecurse
(
    MemberId,
    IncludedMemberId,
    Level
) AS (
    SELECT      Member.Id,
                Member.Id,
                0
    FROM        MemberInput
    INNER JOIN  MemberInputItem
        ON      MemberInputItem.MemberInputId = MemberInput.Id
    INNER JOIN  Member
        ON      Member.Id = MemberInputItem.MemberId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      T_MemberRecurse.MemberId,
                Member2.Id,
                Level + 1
    FROM        T_MemberRecurse
    INNER JOIN  Member
        ON      Member.Id = T_MemberRecurse.IncludedMemberId
    INNER JOIN  MemberReplacement
        ON      MemberReplacement.MemberId = Member.Id
    INNER JOIN  Member Member2
        ON      Member2.Id = MemberReplacement.OriginalMemberId
)
SELECT      Member.Id,
            T_MemberRecurse.IncludedMemberId,
            T_MemberRecurse.Level,

FROM        MemberInput
INNER JOIN  LotsOfTables
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code and sample data?

Comment: Just did. I added the per-record CTE example. A problem with posting examples for this is that none of my examples are even engineered right to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, *‘not engineered right’* – what do you mean by that? Do your present solutions return incorrect results or are they merely not efficient enough?

Comment: They are not efficient enough. As mentioned, the CTE approach does not work, as recursive CTEs don't begin returning second level records until ALL first level records are returned. The CTE produces the correct data, but not in the correct order or speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking about this a bit right now, but first a stab in the dark that could help, due to experiences I've had with linked servers where forcing row-by-row operations improved performance by 2 orders of magnitude.

Turn your CTE into a rowset-returning function with one parameter, the desired Member Id.

Then:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Member M
   CROSS APPLY dbo.MemberChildren(M.Id) C
WHERE
   {Conditions for desired set of Members here}
WITH (FAST 20);
```

Please let me know if this works. The idea is to force the engine to traverse deep-first rather than wide-first. It might be lower overall server performance, but theoretically should let your client begin working with some rows of data.

**Update**

Second idea: get the parent and child information separately and perform, logically, a merge join in the client. (An ordered nested loop that only advances the ordered second/inner input until it mismatches.) Get smaller chunks at once using key ranges or row_number. Or get the entire parent set then get smaller set of child rows.

**Update 2**

Idea 3: Instead of a recursive CTE, use 5 plain vanilla joins to get all the data you need. It sounds awful, but should let you do FAST 100 to get started on the data.

Comment: Hmm. That might work. Was trying to avoid declaring a function to accomplish it, but this might be appropriate, and might work fine. I'll give it a go on Monday.

Comment: CROSS APPLY with a subquery containing an outer reference could theoretically go deep-first, but maybe not. Thus the function.

Comment: If you could put CTEs in a subselect, I'd have solved it awhile ago. =/

Comment: How many levels deep does it go? I was under the impression originally that it was only 2 or 3.

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks so much! I had not known about CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Oddly enough, this improves the total response time.

Comment: Sounds like the data set used too much tempdb. Now it probably can lazy spool. If my answer helped you would you mark it as accepted?